# How to calculate Minkowski functional for this case?

Tags: functional-analysis

I understand what is Minkowski functional for 
$$A = \{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$$ 
It is the norm ||x|| = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. I can attach solution. But what it is in the case
$$A = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: y > x^2 -  1\}$$
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\inf \{r>0: \frac y r >\frac {x^{2}} {r^{2}} -1\}=\inf \{r>0: r^{2}+ry-x^{2} >0\}$. This is $\inf \{r>0: (r+\frac y 2)^{2}>x^{2}+\frac {y^{2}} 4\}$. The answer is therefore $-\frac y 2+\sqrt {x^{2}+\frac {y^{2}} 4}$.